# Any way for EC2 instance to discover which region it is in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, ec2-api-tools

I want to write a script which uses the AWS api within an EC2 instance to modify its own configuration, however to use the `aws` command I need to provide a `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable with the correct region (i.e. 'us-east-1').

If I simply want to issue command pertaining to the instance itself, how can I discover which region to use without hard-coding it in?  I looked through the [instance metadata documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) and couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've been able to find is using the following instance metadata query:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone/
us-east-1a
```

then just shave off the letter at the end to get the region.